# Phalcon module loaded but still class can't be found

Tags: php, apache, phalcon, php-extension

I have installed Phalcon on my vServer and it seems to be loaded,
but if I try to run website I get an error

`PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Phalcon\\Config\\Adapter\\Ini' not found in /home...`

php -v

**PHP 5.6.10 (cli) (built: Jun 11 2015 08:33:51)
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies**

I followed the instructions on Phalcon website.
If I list php modules using `php -m` Phalcon is listed, I don't have
any errors, just don't know why it's not working!

Also, Phalcon is not listed on phpinfo(); page.

Comment: If its not listed in `phpinfo()` u prolly missed something around `extension=phalcon.so` according [this doc](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-get-started-with-phalcon-on-an-ubuntu-12-04-vps). Or you missed restarting apache.

Comment: I triple checked extension=phalcon.so and restarted httpd as well as reboot the whole server. Still phalcon shows on php -m but not in phpinfo();

Comment: `php -m` runs CLI version, `phpinfo()` you prolly watch from non-cli, and both may have separate configs. If you are using Ubuntu and apache2, ensure you have extension enabled in both configs. Also try [what this says](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extension-loaded.php).

Comment: No, I am using CentOS 6.6 and when I do: php --re Phalcon | grep version. I get this Extension [ <persistent> extension #40 phalcon version 2.0.3 ] { Property [ protected static $_version ]. Maybe this can help finding problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looks like you changed the config for the php console client but that config is not the same for the php module in apache.

Review what config is being loaded for apache module

Comment: This answer helped. You could check your `phpinfo` to figure out which php.ini is included and if your module is indeed loaded

Answer (score 2):

When installing phalcon in order to get the extension working make sure to restart nginx / apache2, and if you are running PHP as a module php5-fpm service as well.

```
$ sudo service nginx restart
$ sudo service php5-fpm restart
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem and the reason is that I recompiled php with source code but not recompiled phalcon again after that. I solved that by compiling phalcon again with the correct phpize.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes when phalcon is installed, it creates a separate `.ini` file for itself and adds the extension therein. This is common in mac and linux OS. In such situation, type `php --ini` on the terminal. You should see an out put similar to the following...

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /usr/local/etc/php/5.6
Loaded Configuration File:         /usr/local/etc/php/5.6/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /usr/local/etc/php/5.6/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /usr/local/etc/php/5.6/conf.d/ext-mongodb.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/5.6/conf.d/ext-phalcon.ini
```

As you can see, phalcon created the `/usr/local/etc/php/5.6/conf.d/ext-phalcon.ini` file.

SOLUTION:

Open the file using `sudo nano /usr/local/etc/php/5.6/conf.d/ext-phalcon.ini`, copy the line in which the extension is loaded and paste in `/usr/local/etc/php/5.6/php.ini` if you are using XAMPP, copy the line to `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/php.ini` Restart your server and check if that works.